# vagrant up --no-color, what does it do?

Tags: chef-infra, vagrant

I am learning chef, and found this command from one of the chef tutorial page.

https://learnchef.opscode.com/quickstart/converge/

I know what vagrant up is. but --no-color, I am not sure what this is for.  I searched the entire vagrant web site. still cannot find it.

just curious what this is.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`--no-color` simply disables the colored Vagrant output.

This doesn't appear to be documented at the moment, but searching [Vagrant Github repo](https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/search?q=--no-color&ref=cmdform) shows the following:

[`bin/vagrant`](https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/blob/eb6256316c34c2aa0ce0ad3252f95698aeded8ef/bin/vagrant#L36):

```
# Disable color in a few cases:
#
# * --no-color is anywhere in our arguments
# * STDOUT is not a TTY
# * The terminal doesn't support colors (Windows)
#
if ARGV.include?("--no-color")
  # Delete the argument from the list so that it doesn't
  # cause any invalid arguments down the road.
  ARGV.delete("--no-color")

  opts[:ui_class] = Vagrant::UI::Basic
elsif !Vagrant::Util::Platform.terminal_supports_colors?
  opts[:ui_class] = Vagrant::UI::Basic
elsif !$stdout.tty? && !Vagrant::Util::Platform.cygwin?
  # Cygwin always reports STDOUT is not a TTY, so we only disable
  # colors if its not a TTY AND its not Cygwin.
  opts[:ui_class] = Vagrant::UI::Basic
end
```